# Program for iphone push notifications

Tags: iphone, ssl, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to send push notifications to an app. The program, PushMeBaby, which a co-worker of mine used does not seem to work anymore. I get an -909 error from the SSLwrite command. I couldn't figure out the meaning of it.
Does anyone know a good tool/program that sends push notifications to the APNs-server?
or has anyone know, what the error code means?

Yours
  Bujtor

Comment: Maybe something has changed? Is the certificate still valid?

Answer (score 0):

Well... as it turns out the problem was the certificate.
Apparently it's not that easy to get the correct and valid push-certificate. My boss's third attempt succeeded. The Certificate Signing Request had to be made using the MAC i'm working on, where PushMeBaby is running. Otherwise there was no private key associated with the certificate. In addition the provisioning profil had to be made to only work for that one application.
I hope it helps others having the same problem.